# Centroid of a polygon in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, computational-geometry

I am studying Clojure and functional programming.  I wrote this function to compute the centroid of a polygon specified as a vector of points, e.g. `[[10 20] [0 11] [50 30]]`).

[Here you can read how to compute the centroid of a polygon](https://web.archive.org/web/20120722100030/http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polyarea/).

Can you give me hints and suggestions on how to improve this code from a functional coding style POV?

```
(defn centroid [p]
  "Calcola il centroide del poligono p"
  (let [six*area     (* 6 (polygon-area p))
        n            (count p)
        first-vertex (p 0)
        polygon      (conj p first-vertex)
        x-terms      (atom [])
        y-terms      (atom [])]
     (dotimes [i n]
            (let [point_i   (polygon i)
                  point_i+1 (polygon (inc i))
                  x_i       (point-x point_i)
                  y_i       (point-y point_i)
                  x_i+1     (point-x point_i+1)
                  y_i+1     (point-y point_i+1)]
               (swap! x-terms conj (* (+ x_i x_i+1)
                                      (- (* x_i y_i+1)
                                         (* x_i+1 y_i))))
               (swap! y-terms conj (* (+ y_i y_i+1)
                                      (- (* x_i y_i+1)
                                         (* x_i+1 y_i))))))
     (make-point (/ (reduce + 0 @x-terms) six*area)
                 (/ (reduce + 0 @y-terms) six*area))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the `dotimes`/`atom`s with more functional `loop`/`recur` recursion.

```
(defn centroid [p]
  (let [six*area     (* 6 (polygon-area p))
        n            (count p)
        first-vertex (p 0)
        polygon      (conj p first-vertex)]
     (loop [i       0
            x-terms []
            y-terms []]
       (if (< i n)
         (let [point  (polygon i)
               point' (polygon (inc i))
               x      (point-x point)
               y      (point-y point)
               x'     (point-x point')
               y'     (point-y point')
               dxy    (- (* x y')
                         (* x' y))]
           (recur (inc i)
                  (conj x-terms (* (+ x x') dxy))
                  (conj y-terms (* (+ y y') dxy))))
         (make-point (/ (reduce + 0 x-terms) six*area)
                     (/ (reduce + 0 y-terms) six*area))))))
```

You could also do it through sequences entirely:

```
(defn centroid [p]
  (let [six*area         (* 6 (polygon-area p))
        polygon          (map (juxt point-x point-y) p) ;; turns the points in [x y] pairs
        ;; `juxt` applies each function in order and outputs the results in a list.

        polygon'         (drop 1 (cycle polygon))       ;; circular permutation of polygon 
        ;; `cycle` lazily repeats and concats the input sequence.

        term           (fn [[[x y] [x' y']]]            ;; destructuring a pair of
                                                        ;; [x y] pairs
                         (let [dxy (- (* x y')
                                      (* x' y))] 
                           [(* dxy (+ x x')) (* dxy (+ y y'))]))
        [x-terms yterms] (->> (map list polygon polygon') ;; makes the [point point'] pairs
        ;; when `polygon` is exhausted, the generated sequence stops, so the fact that
        ;; `polygon'` is infinite has no effect.
                              (map term)
                              (apply (partial map list)))] ;; turns the sequence of pairs
                                                           ;; into a pair of sequences
        ;; `apply` turns the list argument in an argument list that it feeds to the function
        ;; - here, a sequence of pairs. `partial` takes a function and some of its arguments
        ;; and returns it with its first arguments set - here, `map list ...`. `map list`
        ;; applied to a list of pairs will call `list` with the first elements of all pairs,
        ;; then with the seconds.

    (make-point (/ (reduce + 0 x-terms) six*area)
                (/ (reduce + 0 y-terms) six*area))))
```

**EDIT:** a(n unefficient) version with `map` galore:

```
(defn centroid [p]
  (let [six*area (* 6 (polygon-area p))
        polygon  (map (juxt point-x point-y) p)
        polygon' (drop 1 (cycle polygon))
        x        (map first polygon)
        x'       (map first polygon')
        y        (map second polygon)
        y'       (map second polygon')
        x**x     (map * x x')
        y**y     (map * y y')
        x**y     (map * x y')
        y**x     (map * y x')
        dxy      (map - x**y y**x)
        x-terms  (map * x**x dxy)
        y-terms  (map * y**y dxy)]
    (make-point (/ (reduce + 0 x-terms) six*area)
                (/ (reduce + 0 y-terms) six*area))))
```

A full `loop`/`recur` version:

```
(defn centroid [[h & t :as p]]
  (let [six*area (* 6 (polygon-area p))
        a        (point-x h)
        b        (point-y h)]
    (loop [x      a
           y      b
           t      t
           x-term 0
           y-term 0]
      (if-let [[h & t] t]
        (let [x'     (point-x h)
              y'     (point-y h)
              dxy    (- (* x y')
                        (* x' y))
              x-term (+ x-term (* dxy (+ x x')))
              y-term (+ y-term (* dxy (+ y y')))]
          (recur x' y' t x-term y-term))
        (let [dxy    (- (* x b)
                        (* a y))
              x-term (+ x-term (* dxy (+ x a)))
              y-term (+ y-term (* dxy (+ y b)))]
          (make-point (/ x-term six*area)
                      (/ y-term six*area)))))))
```

Comment: Wow, the sequences version is very compact though I will need more experience to understand it completely.
Looking at the loop/recur version, I missed that those terms were equal, good catch.
I could also accumulate the sum instead of the terms to sum at the end. It would consume less memory and CPU cycles but I don't know if it would be as clear as it is now.
PS: in the first example the variable is defined as `x**y` and later referred to as `x^y`.

Comment: Thanks, I made the correction. I included some comments in the sequences version, I hope that helps.

Comment: In this line from the 3rd example: `let [ ... x' (map first polygon') ...]`, being `polygon'` an infinite list, wouldn't `map` loop forever?

Comment: `map` returns (immediately) a lazy sequence whose terms will be evaluated when they are iterated through. We never actually iterate over the whole length of `polygon'` (neither on those of x' or y'), but on its "product" with `polygon` - or one of its derivated sequences (which are finite) - through `map`. This "product" has the same length as the shortest of its two parameters. `reduce` provokes a cascading evaluation of these lazy sequences, and only the terms that are needed are evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I am sure I understand well how they works. However I was referring to `y' (map second polygon')` where the only (and shortest) list is `polygon'`, an infinite list. I tried a similar code and it looped for ever..

Comment: Did you try it in a REPL ? Trying to print an infinite sequence will iterate through it (for ever). If you try `(range)` in a REPL, it loops forever. But if you try `(map * (range) (range 100))`, you get the result quickly.

Comment: Yes, I tried it in a REPL. In the _map galore_ version, the code `map`s only over an infinite list in the 6th and 8th line of code (`(map first polygon')` and `(map second polygon')`) since `polygon'` is infinite. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes and no. `polygon'` is potentially infinite. But applying `map` to it doesn't cause an iteration through it ; we create a lazy sequence whose first term is a function of the input sequence's first term, whose second term is a function term is a function of the input sequence's second term, etc. . None of these terms are evaluated until the lazy sequence is iterated through, which means that the input sequence isn't iterated through. In effect `polygon'`, `x'` and `y'` are finite, because they are only read up to the point where `polygon`/`x`/`y` is exhausted.

Comment: Now I got it! I forgot that `map` creates lazy sequences. I need to get used to all these esoteric tools. :)

Answer (score 1):

A fairly concise functional version, incorporating the area calculation:

```
(defn centroid [p]
  (let [pairs  (partition 2 1 (conj p (first p)))
        xp (mapv (fn [[[x1 y1] [x2 y2]]] (- (* x1 y2) (* x2 y1))) pairs)
        twice-area (apply + xp)

        dot-xp (fn [xs] (apply + (map * xs xp)))
        transpose (fn [vv] (apply mapv vector vv))

        pair-sums (mapv #(map (partial reduce +) (transpose %)) pairs)]
    (mapv (comp #(/ % (* 3 twice-area)) dot-xp) (transpose pair-sums))))
```

Then

```
(centroid [[10 20] [0 11] [50 30]])
```

... produces

```
[20 61/3]
```